# How to access data NOAA data through GRADS?

Tags: noaa, grads

I'm trying to get some DAP data from noaa, but can't figure out how to pass variables to it. I've looked and looked and haven't found how to just poke around at it with my browser. The data is located at http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:9090/dods/ruc/ruc20110725/ruc_f17.info (which may become outdated some time after this post sits around.)

I want to access the `ugrd10m` variable with the variables `time`, `latitude`, and `longitude`. Any ideas what url is needed to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [their documentation](http://www.iges.org/grads/gds/doc/user.html#1b), it sounds like you want to point your browser at a URL like:

http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:9090/dods/ruc/ruc20110914/ruc_f17.ascii?ugrd10m[0:1][0:1][0:1]

That will return a table of the ugrd10m values for the first two time/lat/lon points:

```
ugrd10m, [2][2][2]
[0][0], 9.999E20, 9.999E20
[0][1], 9.999E20, 9.999E20

[1][0], 9.999E20, 9.999E20
[1][1], 9.999E20, 9.999E20


time, [2]
734395.0, 734395.0416666666
lat, [2]
16.281, 16.46570909091
lon, [2]
-139.856603, -139.66417731424
```

The number of time/lat/lon points is given under the long description of ugrd10m at the dataset info address:

http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:9090/dods/ruc/ruc20110914/ruc_f17.info

> **time**:     Array of 64 bit Reals [time = 0..18]

means that there are 19 different time values, at indexes 0 to 18.  In this case, the complete dataset can be retrieved by setting all the ranges to the max values:

http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:9090/dods/ruc/ruc20110914/ruc_f17.ascii?ugrd10m[0:18][0:226][0:427]

Comment: Data looks a bit more sane than the below answer. I understand that the 9.999E20 is a fill value? or something that doesn't matter. So you shove a range into the brackets I'll assume?

Comment: Yeah, updated to discuss ranges a bit more.  Much of the data is fill, but there are some real values for a subset of time/lat/lon coordinates.

Comment: I still have a bit to learn towards this, but I have been searching for this kind of help for a long time now. Thanks @blahdiblah.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this reference](http://bmlsc.ucdavis.edu:8080/erddap/tabledap/documentation.html), you can access data with this URL:

http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:9090/dods/ruc/ruc20110914/ruc_00z.asc?ugrd10m&time=19&time=227&time=428

However, I can't confirm the data's validity.

Comment: haha this takes like 5 minutes flat to even load. I know it's giving some sane values, but not until the very bottom.

Comment: @Kyle - as I said, can't confirm its validity; anyways, I tried, hehe.

Comment: I still appreciate it! NOAA has so much data it becomes a beast!